# Flash Develop invalid namespace with AIR 14.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flashdevelop

I'm using *Flash Develop 4.6.2.5*, and I cannot compile my app with AIR versions above `3.9`.

I've tried with `4.0`, `13.0` and `14.0`

```
Packaging: dist\app.apk

project\application.xml: error 102:
Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0 APK setup creation

FAILED.
```

---

Here is all the procedures I've already did:

[image: Step 01]

[image: Step 02]

[image: Step 03]

[image: Step 04]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggle here is the solution:

Switch the order of the PATH at `SetupSDK.bat` *(line ~35)*:

Original:

> `:succeed`
>   `set PATH=`**`%PATH%`**`;%FLEX_SDK%\bin`

Modified:

> `:succeed`
>   `set PATH=%FLEX_SDK%\bin;`**`%PATH%`**

---

The problem should be related with something that I've installed in my system `%PATH%` which is having conflicts with something from `%FLEX_SDK%`, by switching the order you are forcing the packager to give preference to Flex SDK.